# Exporting/Signing Android Project using GSON Library

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I'm using the current GSON libraries in an android app and everything works as expected when the application is built without signing it with the keystore.

When I export the app and sign it, gson fails to parse the Reader into my class.

I've tried signing the app without using proguard but this made no difference. I'm literally lost as to why it is behaving differently when signed.

The line in question is this:

```
Words words = new Words();
words = gson.fromJson(r, Words.class);
```

The object is simply empty when the app is signed.

Comment: Please could you be more specific with the error, what is the exception?

Comment: There is no exception or error occurring, turned out to be the obfuscation after all though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow I would have expected that the obfuscation of proguard is responsible for destroying your model, but I guess now zipalign is messing it up, to ensure that you can parse your json, you could provide specific gson annotations for your model.

Comment: I attempted removing proGuard again and it's now working. I must have missed something first time.

Just need to figure out how to enable proGuard now and have it work.

I'm hoping the answer lies here: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg?r=1077

Comment: Yep that sounds reasonable, but I had a hard time with proguard myself, to make it work with my app. I finally had to remove the direct reference to my model, by using annotations.

Comment: Btw, I felt Jackson is a much better (faster) object mapper!

Comment: I was looking into Jackson, but it looked like the response had to first be saved to file...? 

Implementing the following lines in the proguard.cfg did the trick. 

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keep class com.mypackagename.MyClass { *; }